# What is the history of the name cursor for database connection objects?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, database, sqlite

I have been looking around for the history of the term - cursor - for database connection objects.

For example: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html  explains Once you have a Connection, you can create a Cursor object and call its execute() method to perform SQL commands:

Can anyone explain how this term cursor came about and whether there is any relation to the curses libraries?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about code you've written. 

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  Do you have any suggestion as to where it should be asked?

Comment: "Curses" is probably a play on the word "cursor", which can mean a position in a text editing console as well as a position in a database query. But I'm not an expert in technical etymology.

Comment: FYI, programmers.stackexchange.com is usually a better place to ask this kind of questions which relate to programming but are not specific programming questions per se.

Comment: google cursor+etymology ... basically, it comes from the runner on a slide rule (yeah, I'm old enough not only to know what that is, but to have used them. I even still own one.)

Comment: As for curses, straight from Wikipedia: `The name is a pun on the term “cursor optimization”.` ... please don't waste your time and ours with such simple lookup questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28computers%29#Origin_of_the_term):

> Cursor is Latin for 'runner.' A cursor is the name given to the transparent slide engraved with a hairline that is used for marking a point on a slide rule. The term was then transferred to computers through analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Should also look at simple terminology for databases, such as [here, in the magic world known as Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29)

Comment: I was looking underneath the Wiki entry for SQL.  Didn't see the one you mentioned.  However, it mentions that a cursor is, but not the etymology of the word.  Is that in the article you mentioned?

Comment: @Paul Learn a very basic skill: When an extremely narrow search doesn't find what you're looking for, widen it.

Comment: the OED (Oxford English Dictionary (1987 edition)) devotes about a quarter of a column to the word cursor
  from the latin for "runner" or "agent"

Comment: - 1 runner, running messenger
   - 2 a part of a mathematical, astronomical or surveying instrument, which slides back and forth (as in the cursor of a slide-rule[link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Slide_rule_scales_front.jpg))
 - 3 - in medieval universities a Bachelor of Theology giving lectures required for a doctorate
@Jim Balter

Comment: compare the current-position indicator in a video display terminal (the block/caret/underscore) to the movement bacvk and forth of the cursor for the slide rule, and then consider the action of the cursor in the database moving back and forth within the selected set of records and indicating the current conceptual position within the retrieved set of records.